# Is it possible to use @pattern with a dynamic regex in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Constant.java file with regex string:

```
String regex = "some regex string";
```

and a serializable Bean class using this regex:

```
My Bean{

 @Pattern(regex=Constant.regex, flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE, message="Some message")
 private String code;
...
}
```

I need to read the regex from DB and not from the Constat file. Is there any way i can do it??
Any suggestion/work arounds ?

Regards

Comment: No you cannot as annotations are static, as this isn't a Spring based annotation Spring cannot do any post processing. Your only solution would be to implement your own constraint validator which would retrieve the value from the database each time a validation is done.